# Ordering an array which is inside of another array based in an array keys order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Im exporting a grid to xls, I have an array $data which holds the informations inside of a numeric array, like:

Array
(
           [0] => Array
                (
                          [Field1] => "Value"
                          [Field2] => "Different value"
                          [Field3] => "Another alue"
                )
)
Where [0] is the first line of the grid (and the grid can have up to 10k lines or just 3)

But the user can change the order of the fields or add more (or even hide the ones is on the grid), so I have another array which holds exactly which Fields are visible and their current orders "$currentOrder" (both arrays - the numeric one inside $data and $currentOrder - have the same amount and name of keys).
I've been having trouble to get inside the numeric array and order it's field like $currentOrder's (and change the values to the right field)

 If my $currentOrder is
Array
(
                  [Field3] => ""
                  [Field1] => ""
                  [Field2] => ""
)

My $data output have to be
Array
(
           [0] => Array
                (
                          [Field3] => "Another value"
                          [Field1] => "Value"
                          [Field2] => "Different Value"
                )
)

Comment: Can you narrow down more specifically what you want?

Comment: Also add sample for $currentOrder array and your desired output.

Comment: Can you also provide an example input and output that way it will be easy for us to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. It uses [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to reorder each element of `$data` according to the key order in `$current_order`.

```
$data = array(array('Field1'=>'Value',
                    'Field2'=>'Different value',
                    'Field3'=>'Another value')
              );
$currentOrder = array('Field3'=>'',
                      'Field1'=>'',
                      'Field2'=>'');

$output = array_map(function ($arr) use ($currentOrder) {
    $newarr = array();
    foreach (array_keys($currentOrder) as $key)
        $newarr[$key] = $arr[$key];
    return $newarr;
}, $data);

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field3] => Another value
            [Field1] => Value
            [Field2] => Different value
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like It:-

```
foreach($urarr as $key => $val){
    ksort($urarr[$key], SORT_NUMERIC);
}
```